# F# One extension method reference another

Tags: f#, extension-methods

```
[<Extension>]
static member ToOrganizationRequest<'T when 'T :> OrganizationRequest> (entity: Entity) =
    let request = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof<'T>) :?> OrganizationRequest
    request.Parameters.Item "Target" <- entity
    request

[<Extension>]
static member ToOrganizationRequest<'T when 'T :> OrganizationRequest> (entities: seq<Entity>) = 
    entities
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.ToOrganizationRequest<'T>())
```

The second extensionmethod is not able to reference the first, so

|> Seq.map (fun x -> x.ToOrganizationRequest<'T>())

fails, because im not able to use ToOrganizationRequest.
Is there any way to make it understand the reference?

Comment: static members are available by `TypeName.StaticMember`, so try to use that instead of `this.StaticMember`

Comment: What do you mean? That i should be able to do something like Entity.ToOrganizationRequest<'T> ? Because i am not able to do that.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need your extension method to be visible in C#, you can (and probably should) extend the `Entity` type like this instead:

```
type Entity with
    member this.ToOrganizationRequest<'T when 'T :> OrganizationRequest>() =
        let request = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof<'T>) :?> OrganizationRequest
        request.Parameters.Item "Target" <- entity
        request
```

This will allow your second C# style extension method to function as you originally wrote it:

```
[<Extension>]
type Ext =
    [<Extension>]
    static member ToOrganizationRequest<'T when 'T :> OrganizationRequest> (entities: seq<Entity>) = 
        entities
        |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.ToOrganizationRequest<'T>())
```

If you do need them in C#, you'll have to call the other extension method statically within the type that the extension methods are defined within.

```
[<Extension>]
type Ext =
    [<Extension>]
    static member ToOrganizationRequest<'T when 'T :> OrganizationRequest> (entity: Entity) =
        let request = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof<'T>) :?> OrganizationRequest
        request.Parameters.Item "Target" <- entity
        request

    [<Extension>]
    static member ToOrganizationRequest<'T when 'T :> OrganizationRequest> (entities: seq<Entity>) = 
        entities  
        |> Seq.map (Ext.ToOrganizationRequest)
```

You can read more about the various types of extension methods within the F# documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/type-extensions#generic-extension-methods).

Comment: I am calling the code from C#. Worken perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: Actually @TheInnerLight F#-style extension methods won't work for the second method, because the `this` should be `seq<Entity>`; you would need to write `type seq<Entity> with ...` and that's not allowed.

Comment: @Tarmil Thanks, I think the moral of the story is to not write answers in haste :)